# Are the Bounty Hunter Wars books canon?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, boba-fett

The written Bounty Hunter Wars trilogy describes a power struggle within the galaxy-wide bounty hunters guild which causes the organization to fracture. One important character in the series is Boba Fett. Much of the events in the series take place after Boba Fett supposedly fights his way out of the Sarlaac- however the writers of the 'new canon' have been rather vague about whether Fett survived being swallowed by the Sarlaac.

Are any of the events in the books leading up to the Sarlaac canon? Did the guild tear itself apart as described?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, Legends books (or other media) are not canon under the Disney canon policy unless they are explicitly referenced in new media. Thus unless some book makes explicit references to the *Bounty Hunter Wars* books, they aren't canon.

You asked specifically about the Guild and Boba Fett's fate. There hasn't been much of anything about the Bounty Hunters Guild (or the bounty hunters themselves) in the new canon, so we don't know anything about what happened there. Nor do we know if Boba Fett survived the Sarlacc pit. His [StarWars.com databank entry](http://www.starwars.com/databank/boba-fett) summarizes pretty much all of his Disney canon appearances, but is rather vague about what happens to him after he falls into the pit.

Things get a little murkier when you look at interviews though. Jonathan Rinzler, author and editor for Lucas Licensing's book division, stated the following in a 2014 Reddit Ask Me Anything:

> **Q:** Jonathan, In your mind, does Boba Fett Escape the Sarlacc Pit?
>
> **A:** Yes, he does. I have been in meetings with George where he confirms that Fett survived. If it comes from George then it’s true!

Make of that what you will.

Comment: And I was thinking the upside of Disney rewriting SW history was the possibility that Fett DID die.

Comment: @Nu'Daq It's not clear how much sway George Lucas has nowadays, so he might very well be dead. Personally, I think that he's too marketable to die and that he'll eventually come back.